# Multiplication program

Tags: python-2.7

I am making this multiplication program in python 2.7.5 for my sister, and I don't know how to count the correct answers.  Here is the code:

```
import easygui
for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]:
    answer = easygui.enterbox("What is " + str(i) + ' times 8?')
    if int(answer) == i * 8:
        easygui.msgbox("That is correct!")
    else:
        easygui.msgbox("Wrong!")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just add a variable to keep count for you?

```
import easygui
correct_answers = 0 # start with none correct
for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]:
    answer = easygui.enterbox("What is " + str(i) + ' times 8?')
    if int(answer) == i * 8:
        easygui.msgbox("That is correct!")
        correct_answers += 1 # increment
    else:
        easygui.msgbox("Wrong!")
```

You could improve your program by making the base number a variable, too, and using Python's `str.format()` rather than addition:

```
base = 8
...
    answer = easygui.enterbox("What is {0} times {1}?".format(i, base))
    if int(answer) == i * base:
        ...
```

Comment: The reason that I did not is because I just started python and did not know how.